# How to enable push notification types from settings bundle when registering for push notification?

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, push-notification, appsettings

I have created settings bundle and also three switches for alert, sound and badge. I am also getting 0 or 1 according to switch(On/Off). Now how do I enable only selected notification types when calling this method

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(here I want to set types from settings)];
```

how do I set types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass one (or the OR of multiple) [UIRemoteNotificationType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiremotenotificationtype?language=objc), like

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
     registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
         (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
```

I recommend that you enable all the types here.  This would create a new settings for the App under Push Notification settings in the Settings app, which is the standard place for user configuration of push notification.

I would argue against having your own configuration in your app settings bundle.

Comment: You mean if i enable these three types the app automatically creates those three switches for pushnotification setting in settings app?

Comment: Correct and the user can then disable the undesirable notification types there.